# "Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: webkitSpeechRecognition is not a constructor

Tags: typescript, speech-recognition, polyfills, webkitspeechrecognition

I'm trying to get SpeechRecognition to work in Firefox and understand that it's a problem as of last month DEC 2019.

This is the code I'm following starting at Basic Usage

[WebKitSpeechRecognition](https://codeburst.io/html5-speech-recognition-api-670846a50e92)

Here's my implementation in Typescript:

```
 /**
 * Start voice recognition.
 *
 * @param force (optional) force restart of listener service
 */
 public async startVoiceRecognition(force?: boolean): Promise<void> {

 console.log('Speech Recognition: ', window.SpeechRecognition, window.webkitSpeechRecognition)

 // **START New Code following example in link above**
 window.SpeechRecognition = window.webkitSpeechRecognition || window.SpeechRecognition;

     if ((window.webkitSpeechRecognition) && this.fSpeechRecognitionRunning) {
          // speech recognition API supported
          console.log('API Supported');
          this.recognition = new window.SpeechRecognition();
     } else {
          // speech recognition API not supported
          console.log('API Not Supported');  
          return;  
     }

     // **END New Code following example in link above**

     // **Original Code**
     // Check if Speech Recognition is available in this browser
     **if (!(window.webkitSpeechRecognition) && !this.fSpeechRecognitionRunning) {
         // console.log('Error: Speech not supported');
         return;
     }**

}
```

What I keep getting is this:

ERROR Error: "Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: **webkitSpeechRecognition** is not a constructor

I know it's in the BOLDED lines because when I swap out webkitSpeechRecognition with just SpeechRecognition, I still get the same error with the different item...

ERROR Error: "Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: **SpeechRecognition** is not a constructor

Finally, here's my polyfill.ts...

```
declare global {
  interface Window {
    AudioContext: typeof window.AudioContext;
    webkitAudioContext: typeof window.AudioContext;
    webkitSpeechRecognition: typeof window.SpeechRecognition;
  }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

According to MDN [https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/SpeechRecognition/SpeechRecognition], only Chrome supports SpeechRecognition. (as of Jan 2020)

Comment: True, but I found this... not sure how to implement:  https://hacks.mozilla.org/2016/01/firefox-and-the-web-speech-api/ and this works on FF.  http://mdn.github.io/web-speech-api/speak-easy-synthesis/

Comment: Askommerville, that link you posted is 404 NOT FOUND